# Undefined property: App\Ticket::$status laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

Ticket.php

```
public function getStatusAttribute()
{
    if ( $this->status == 0 ) {
        return ['label' => 'closed', 'bs_class' => 'badge badge-secondary'];
    }
    if ( $this->status == 1 ) {
        return ['label' => 'answered', 'bs_class' => 'badge badge-success'];
    }
    return ['label' => 'waiting', 'bs_class' => 'badge badge-warning'];
}
```

ticket.blade.php

```
<td>
    @php $status = $ticket->status @endphp
    <span class="{{ $status['bs_class'] }}">
    {{ $status['label'] }}
  </span>
</td>
```

migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->string('diaphragmUnit');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(0);
        $table->text('message');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I want to show the `label` of the status of tickets.

But it says:

> Undefined property: App\Ticket::$status

**Edit**

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $tickets = Ticket::latest()->paginate(25);
    return view('Admin.tickets.index', compact('tickets'));
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the line triggering the problem and the definition of that `Ticket` class

Comment: The logic here seems flawed. Your `getStatusAttribute` which should be called when you access `->status` but you also do this within the `getStatusAttribute` itself which would result in an infinite loop if it had worked.

Comment: you are not returning 'status' object but an array... so you need to return array named 'status' with those values so that you can access them in view as $status->XYZ

Comment: @vins Can you send complete code?

Comment: No, please: can **you** send the complete code, or other attempts to resolve the problem? If you are accessing that `status` property, please show where you defined it

Comment: Please share more details. You still haven't shown any code that defines the property `$status` on the class `Ticket`, nor have you shown your attempts to resolve the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to provide an argument in the accessor:

```php
public function getStatusAttribute($status)
{
    if ( $status == 0 ) {
        return ['label' => 'closed', 'bs_class' => 'badge badge-secondary'];
    }
    if ( $status == 1 ) {
        return ['label' => 'answered', 'bs_class' => 'badge badge-success'];
    }
    return ['label' => 'waiting', 'bs_class' => 'badge badge-warning'];
}
```

and so you will also change the `$this->status` to simply `$status`

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with your migration file. Its actually coming from the point where you tried accessing

> $ticket->status

In your ticket.blade.php. Reason is because in your service getStatusAttribute, the response data does not have "ticket" property instead your return value should be

```
    public function getStatusAttributeService()
        {
            if ( $this->status == 0 ) {
                $status = ['status'=> ['label' => 'closed', 'bs_class' => 'badge badge-secondary']];
            }
            if ( $this->status == 1 ) {
                $status = ['status'=>['label' => 'answered', 'bs_class' => 'badge badge-success']];
            }
            $status = ['status'=> ['label' => 'waiting', 'bs_class' => 'badge badge-warning']];

 return view('callYourViewHere',['ticket'=>$status]);
        }
```

Comment: I get this error again `syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']' `

Comment: Yeah and that is because I didn't format the code properly. I thought you would understand.

Comment: It's just missing some quotes: `['ticket' => ['status' =>...`

Comment: @Ezugudor in the code above value of 'label' will always be 'waiting', and also it will throw error since the return statement is outside the function

Comment: @vins no way. "$this->status " tells you that there is a status somewhere defined in the global space. So that is not the concern here. And yes you were correct with the second observation about the return value and I have made the correction and updated my answer. Thanks. The major problem here is proper object structure as seen from the blade file. Therefore , response data should be "tickets->status->propertyName"

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** exact **tested solution** it is just meant for **providing some idea** you may need to fix some error probably, ps : IT IS NOT THE EXACT SOLUTION NOR HAS BEEN TESTED, so please dont judge it

```
public function getStatusAttribute()
{
    if ( $this->status == 0 ) {
        $status = array('label' => 'closed', 
                        'bs_class' => 'badge badge-secondary'
                        );
        
    }
    else if ( $this->status == 1 ) {
        $status = array('label' => 'answered', 
                        'bs_class' => 'badge badge-success'
                        );
        
    }
    else 
    {
        $status = array( 'label' => 'waiting',
                         'bs_class' => 'badge badge-warning'
                         );
    }

   
    return view('yourViewname', ['status' => $status] );
}
```

in yourview

```
<td>   
    <span class="{{ $status['bs_class'] }}">
    {{ $status['label'] }}
  </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `getStatusAttribute` method, you have to access status from `$attributes` property,

```php
public function getStatusAttribute()
{
    $status = $this->attributes['status'] ?? null;

    if ( $status == 0 ) {
        return ['label' => 'closed', 'bs_class' => 'badge badge-secondary'];
    }
    if ( $status == 1 ) {
        return ['label' => 'answered', 'bs_class' => 'badge badge-success'];
    }
    return ['label' => 'waiting', 'bs_class' => 'badge badge-warning'];
}
```